# Why are brackets not needed for the first index of an array in x86 assemby?

Tags: assembly, x86, masm

if you have

```
numArray BYTE 10h, 20h, 30h, 40h, 50h

mov al, numArray       = AL = 10h;
mov al, [numArray + 1] = AL = 20h;
mov al, [numArray + 2] = AL = 30h;
```

Why do we not need the brackets to access the first index? If we dont use the brackets, arent we just storing the address instead of the actual value?

Comment: This looks like it might just be MASM/TASM from the `BYTE` to me, it might be MASM acting weird with its "variables". Please add a tag for which assembler you are using.

Comment: MASM @mediocrevegetable1

Comment: You don't need `[]` in the other two, either.  If you find MASM syntax weird, use NASM where memory operands *always* need `[]`, and bare stuff symbols are always immediates (the address), exactly like you expected.  i.e. you don't need to look somewhere else to see if something was a label or an `equ` to see how a certain line is going to assemble (load or mov-immediate).